# Opengl Shader, what's the gl_FragColor's alpha components?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, cocos2d-x

I think it'll be a little bit simple answer.
But I can't find the answer with googling.
It's OpenGLES shader thing. I am using cocos2d-x engine.

This is my fragment shader code.

```
precision lowp float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 u_lightPosition;

void main()
{
    vec4 col=texture2D(u_texture,v_texCoord);

    mediump float lightDistance = distance(gl_FragCoord, u_lightPosition);
    mediump float alpha = 100.0/lightDistance;
    alpha = min(alpha, 1.0);
    alpha = max(alpha, 0.0);
    col.w = alpha;
    //col.a = alpha;


    gl_FragColor=col;

}
```

I just want to give opacity in some circle area. So I change the color's w value because I thought it's the alpha value of the texel. But the result was very odd. 
I am afraid it's not alpha value.

Even if I set the value to 1.0 for testing, whole sprite change to be bright and white.

Its vertex shader is very normal, there is nothing special to attached.

Any idea please.

**Updated:** For reference, I attach some result image.

case 1)

```
col.w = alpha;
```

[image]

case 2)

```
col.w = 1.0
```

[image]

and normal texture before applying shader.)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're asking, What is the meaning of the w component of the vec4 assigned to gl_FragColor.

Comment: Resultingly, you're right, gl_FragColor's w. :)

Comment: As far as I know, you're doing it right. You may need to show us (a) what the input texture looks like, and (b) what your current output looks like.

Comment: I put the result sample. :)

Comment: What's your blend mode?

Comment: As Tommy said, you should add your current blend mode to the question. On a side note, you can replace your min/max lines with [clamp](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/clamp.xhtml) like so: `clamp(alpha, 0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. I checked the Blend mode again.  it's GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA. I think it's reason to be brighten.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [GL ES 2.0 reference card](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf) defines:

> **Variable** 
>  mediump vec4 gl_FragColor;
>
> **Description** 
>  fragment color
>
> **Units or coordinate system** 
>  RGBA color

It further states:

> **Vector Components** 
>  In addition to array numeric subscript syntax,
>   names of vector components are denoted by a single letter. Components
>   can be swizzled and replicated, e.g.: pos.xx, pos.zy
>
> **{x, y, z, w}** Use when accessing vectors that represent points or normals
>
> **{r, g, b, a}** Use when accessing vectors that represent colors
>
> **{s, t, p, q}** Use when accessing vectors that represent texture coordinates

So, sure, using `.a` would be more idiomatic but it's explicitly the case that what you store to `.w` is the output alpha for `gl_FragColor`.

To answer the question you've set as a title rather than the question in the body, the value returned by `texture2D` will be whatever is correct for that texture. Either an actual stored value if the texture is `GL_RGBA` or `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` or else 1.0.

So you're outputting alpha correctly.

If your output alpha isn't having the mixing effect that you expect then you must have `glBlendFunc` set to something unexpected, possibly involving `GL_CONSTANT_COLOR`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works well. vec4 col=texture2D(u_texture,v_texCoord);
    mediump float lightDistance = distance(gl_FragCoord, u_lightPosition);
    mediump float alpha = 100.0/lightDistance;
    alpha = clamp(alpha, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0 - alpha;